# How to connect to remote system in Windows 7 when another user is already logged in

Tags: windows-7

I have 2 systems say for example machine **A** and machine **B**
Machine **A** has 2 users **A1** and **A2** and both have administrator rights.

From machine **B** I am connecting to machine **A1** via mstsc(remote connection) and while the connection is active if some one logs in machine **A2** then it pops the following message

> Another user is currently logged on this computer.If you continue this user has to discontinue from this system.Do you wish to continue?**

So what is the way to login from 2 different users at the same time?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/631819/how-can-i-enable-multiple-users-login-at-a-time-in-remote-system

Comment: @Peter unfortuately mine is not windows server

Comment: Surely the message itself is the answer? This question is like "I tried to do X but found out that I can't due to Y. How can I do X?" to which the answer is "you can't, due to Y". (I don't accept the hack as a valid approach due to illegality!)

Comment: Regular Windows versions do not support multi-user, simultaneous log-ons. However, this is available in Windows Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**

### DISCLAIMER (courtesy of [Daniel Petri](https://www.petri.com/author/daniel-petri))

> Before you begin, I need to warn you that patching the file
>   and allowing more than one concurrent Remote Desktop session will
>   violate a few lines in the Windows 7 EULA. Proceed with caution and
>   at your own risk. I shall not be liable for any damage caused to you,
>   your computer, your data or your dog/cat because of this.

There is no way to do this via built-in tools in Windows 7.
There exist some 3rd party tools however, [termsrv patch](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows.html) for example. (I used it myself)

If you decide to try this, be aware that you're doing so **AT YOUR OWN RISK**, this is a "hack" (if you want to call it that) of your OS, it may happen that you run into weird / unacceptable problems.

Comment: You're also violating the EULA. Home versions of Windows have only single concurrent user licences. Hence the restriction....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are completely right. I will add a "disclaimer" of some sort.