# How to enable two users simultaneous access to a Windows instance in AWS?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services

I have an instance of Windows Server 2008 inside AWS.

To access it I and another developer use a Remote Desktop client file. The issue is we cannot have access to the same instance at the same time.

Is there a way we can both access this server instance simultaneously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable multiple users login at a time in remote system?](http://superuser.com/questions/631819/how-can-i-enable-multiple-users-login-at-a-time-in-remote-system)

Comment: The proposed duplicate addresses how to allow *more than 2* simultaneous users.  The OP only needs 2 simultaneous connections and the duplicate question does not provide an answer for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, yes you can using Terminal Server, but not for free.

Longer answer:
Microsoft describes [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754288(v=ws.10).aspx) how to set up a Terminal Server role. However, to use this, you would need Client Access Licenses. On eBay you can find 5 CAL's for around USD 150.

Comment: The OP only has two users needing simultaneous access.  Microsoft permits this without requiring additional licenses to be purchased or RDSH to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Server permits two simultaneous remote connections** out of the box as described in this [MSKB document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947723):

> At any point in time, there can be two active remote administration sessions [to the server]. To start a remote administration session, you must be a member of the Administrators group on the server to which you are connecting.

No special configuration is required other than to enable Remote Desktop in System Properties and logon with a user account that is a member of the Administrators group.  Further, each of you should either:

1. Logon with separate Windows user accounts, or
2. To use the same Windows user account but in separate logon instances, edit the local group policy setting `Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Connections/Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session` and set it to **Disabled**.