# Can I configure Remote Desktop Connection for multiple users in the same time?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-connection

How  I  can have a multiple users Remote Desktop Connection to a Windows Server in the same time ?

Comment: This is most of all a licensing question: You need either a DAL or a CAL to make the server allow you to connect multiple times concurrently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable multiple users login at a time in remote system?](https://superuser.com/q/631819/173513)

Answer (score 1):

You need to purchase [CALs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-server-2016-remote-desktop-services/dg7gmgf0ds1h/0006) (client access licenses).  The link I sent is for Server 2016.  I am not sure if the pricing is different for Server 2012.  I would just call Microsoft and ask them what the best option and pricing would be.

Comment: Microsoft only sells CALs for the latest version of Windows server. However a newer CAL entitles one to connect to older server versions.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator that must have changed since the last time I had to buy CALs. It has been about a decade...