# Multiple RDP sessions at the same time with the same credentials

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

Can you RDP into a workstation with the same credentials from different machines at the same time? or will one user be logged out so that only one session may remain active at a time.

This

[How can I enable multiple users login at a time in remote system?](https://superuser.com/questions/631819/how-can-i-enable-multiple-users-login-at-a-time-in-remote-system)

question answers this one w.r.t. distinct users.

Comment: If you use a machine(client1) and log into a server machine using RDP, then go to another machine (client2) and log into that same server, again using RDP with the same credentials, then client1 will be logged off and client 2 will assume control of that  session. This will not create a second session.

Comment: It does happen, regularly I get prompted which of my disconnected sessions do I want to reconnect to, I feel that it might be due to different screen resolutions , but i never found it repeatable.  It’s from the same client so it’s not something like client version issue.

Comment: Windows assumes there is a single session per user, so it will try to log you in to the existing session, if there is one.